# Optional parameters in fabric chaincode method

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I'm working on a simple nodejs chaincode for a fabric network, and I'd like one method of the chaincode to have optional parameters.

The setting is a class that extends `fabric-contract-api`:

```js
'use strict';
const { Contract} = require('fabric-contract-api');
class testContract extends Contract { 
    // chaincode methods
}
```

I tried 2 approaches and both failed:

- I was expecting it to follow the nodejs notation for optional parameters, so:

```js
    async getAllMarks(ctx, studentId, subject = null) {
        // return marks
    }
```

However, if I call the chaincode with 2 parameters I get an error stating that ony 1 is expected.

- Then I tried with a workaround, remembering that an unset function parameter is `undefined` and `undefined == null` in js:

```js
    async getAllMarks(ctx, studentId, subject) {
        if (subject != null) {
            // filter marks for subject
        }
        // return marks
    }
```

In this case the call fails if it has only 1 parameter, 2 are expected.

#### So: does this mean that it's not possible to have optional parameters in fabric chaincodes or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two options:

1. Send explicitly `subject` from your client as "" or similar and attend it suitably in your chaincode.
2. Send one only parameter, a JSON Object with 2 fields (`studentID` and `subject`). Then `subject` may be optional if you want.

I usually use second approach (my chaincodes are written in Go, but it must be the same with NodeJS). I find it cleaner (although maybe it is a little bit slower).

In general, do not think in a very NodeJS-centric way at that entry point. You may have Go/NodeJS/Java chaincodes and NodeJS/Java clients communicating via GRPC in a compatible way.

Comment: So chaincode functions have a fixed signature with no optional parameters. This is an arbitrary choice from the Fabric devs, since GRPC supports optional parameters by setting them to a default value if missing. It is a legit choice, but I would prefer to see it documented somehow.
I ended up implementing a different wrapper chaincode function which lacks `subject` and calls internally the other function with `subject=null`

Comment: Not really sure about the exact reason. The first chaincode library was the Go one. Go does not support optional parameters. So that may be a reason. Your solution is perfectly valid (although it can be confusing if you "abuse" and create to many wrappers). For more complex inputs, is preferred to model input objects.

Comment: I see, thanks. There's no risk to become confusing in this case since there are just 4 methods in the contract, but I'll keep in mind your suggestion for the future